Paying toll roads in Poland with under 3.5 tons rental car
I recently drove around Poland in a private rental car under 3.5 tons, specifically around Krakow, Wroclaw, Lodz, Katowice, and back to Krakow. I'm trying to understand if I may have missed any road tolls I should have paid.
I did pay once at a toll booth, but in other places, I encountered either unmanned booths with open gates or no booths or gates at all. I also had issues installing the e-TOLL app, and people at gas stations told me that I don't need to pay unless there is a manned gate.
Is it possible that I accidentally didn't pay for some toll roads? If so, what can I do now to avoid a fine?
I appreciate any clarification on this matter!

Were other cars passing through those unmanned toll gates also without stopping and paying?

If you had to pay in any way there and you didn't, there is not much you can do now, until you get forwarded a fine from the rental car company. Then you can try to maybe resolve it without paying, which probably will be quite challenging.

@Johnnyjanko yes, other cars were passing there as well without stopping and paying. kirbby thanks
